# How can I compare the first words of two lists and print the second word of the matching entries?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Hello as an example I have the following files:

```
file1
aa1
aa2
aa3
aa4
aa5
aa6
aa7
aa8
aa9
aa10

file2
aa1 1.1.1.1
aa2 1.1.1.2
aa4 1.1.1.4
aa6 1.1.1.6
aa11 1.1.1.11
aa8 1.1.1.8
```

I need to keep all lines of file1 one but print the IPs of the matching lines. Something like:

```
file3
aa1 1.1.1.1
aa2 1.1.1.2
aa3
aa4 1.1.1.4
aa5
aa6 1.1.1.6
aa7
aa8 1.1.1.8
aa9
aa10
```

I was trying to do some script using two for loops and awk, but it does not work as expected.

Comment: Please show the code for your attempts so far and why they did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard `join` command:

```
$ join -a 1 file1 file2
aa1 1.1.1.1
aa2 1.1.1.2
aa3
aa4 1.1.1.4
aa5
aa6 1.1.1.6
aa7
aa8 1.1.1.8
aa9
aa10
```

This tool joins two files together on a shared "key" column. The `-a 1` keeps all unpaired lines from file 1.

Comment: This doesn't actually work since the original input files are not in sorted order.

Comment: @b4hand: we don't know that, and this is a really nice solution for sorted `file1`.

Comment: The examples are not sorted. See my solution that first sorts the input files. Specifically if you use your solution, you'll see these error messages: `join: file2:5: is not sorted: aa11 1.1.1.11` and `join: file1:10: is not sorted: aa10`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your original input files are not actually sorted lexicographically, you can't do what you want in a singular linear pass which is what most Unix tools assume, but this will produce similar output as long as you don't need to preserve the original input order:

```
$ join -a1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
aa1 1.1.1.1
aa10
aa2 1.1.1.2
aa3
aa4 1.1.1.4
aa5
aa6 1.1.1.6
aa7
aa8 1.1.1.8
aa9
```

And here's a solution using Perl that preserves the original line order by storing all the data in memory and using a hash to do the lookup:

```
$ perl -n -e 'BEGIN { open my $f, "<", "file2"; %m = map { chomp; split } <$f> } chomp; print "$_ $m{$_}\n";' file1
aa1 1.1.1.1
aa2 1.1.1.2
aa3 
aa4 1.1.1.4
aa5 
aa6 1.1.1.6
aa7 
aa8 1.1.1.8
aa9 
aa10
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `awk` would be

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{line[$0]=""; next} ($1 in line){line[$1]=$2} END{for ( i in line) print i, line[i]}' file1 file2 | sort -n
aa10 
aa1 1.1.1.1
aa2 1.1.1.2
aa3 
aa4 1.1.1.4
aa5 
aa6 1.1.1.6
aa7 
aa8 1.1.1.8
aa9
```

Answer (score 0):

How about looping through `file1` and for each word asking for doing `grep` from file 2, and if found printing `grep` output else printing word from `file1`?